# How to use es6 syntax to import a function module in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a simple module. Use for checking variable type.

**index.js**

```
'use strict';
var typeOf = function (variable) {
    return ({}).toString.call(variable).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
};
module.exports = typeOf;
```

**index.d.ts**

```
export default typeOf;
declare function typeOf(value:any):string;
```

Here how I use it.

```
import typeOf from 'lc-type-of';
typeOf(value);
```

But the code dosen't work as expect. The typeOf function came out undefined error. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you export node like with Javascript:

```
module.exports = something;
```

in Typescript import it like :

```
import * as something from "./something"
```

and in the definition

```
// Tell typescript about the signature of the function you want to export
declare const something: ()=> void ;

// tell typescript how to import it     
declare module something {
      // Module does Nothing , it simply tells about it's existence
}

// Export 
export =  something;
```

Comment: I changed as you said. But the compiler said ```error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof "E:/project/node_modules/lc-type-of/index"' has no compatible call signatures.```

Comment: After adding your addition code. It works now!  Awsome mate! Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask you why I have to declare a module ? It is just a function.

Comment: how would you import it if its not a module ? :)

Comment: You can actually just export the function @Dan! :)

Comment: @Oskar , from typescript ... yes, but How would Typescript  resolve the "function" if haven't told where it is ? or coming from ?. beacuase he is DECLARING a function , not writing it in Typescript

Comment: @Dan. That make sense. And why it dosen't use export default syntax instead of 'export = something'? I though it just like es6 style.

Comment: default export is es6 and up, different syntax to export and import , you used commonjs export syntax, so you should import it like that

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you so much!